# .lib with same md5 on debug and release builds

Tags: c++, c, qt, dll, shared-libraries

I got a qmake subdirs project which builds 3 sub projects:

- a C/C++ library (.lib and .dll)
- a Qt library which is based on the previous (.lib and .dll)
- an application which demo the use of the libraries

I noticed debug and release buids of .lib files seem to generate the same, same md5sum for debug and release builds.

It happens for both, C/C++ and Qt, libraries.

The .dll files are different for debug and release.

Then I checked other libraries .lib around here and they have different md5sum for debug and release builds.

What does it mean to have (or not) same .lib for debug and release?

Comment: Are they they same file size? Are they the same data?

Comment: Same md5sum implies that, right?

Comment: MD5 is an extremely weak hashing method and really shouldn't be trusted as a security measure, but yes, in theory that's what it means. For anything serious, I'd suggest SHA2 256 or 512. It's worth checking that you're computing the hashes on the correct files. Maybe they're both empty or consist of just some uniform boiler plate?

Comment: Doesn't the .lib file contain the list of symbols being exported from the DLL, or something along those lines? In that case, it makes sense that it's the same across build types. (Not making this an answer because I don't know 100%)

Comment: How can I check that?